# Getting data from google calendar in php

Tags: php, google-calendar-api

I have about 100 events in one year on my google calendar.
I also have users registered on my webiste.

I want that every day my system checks for upcoming events and send mail to useers for events happenning tomorrow.

I am thinking of setting up cron job that runs every day.

But how can i get the events from Google Calendar using php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not common way to answer in such a way here on SO, but **have you even tried to google**?

http://code.google.com/apis/calendar/data/1.0/developers_guide_php.html

This is the first link for query "google calendar php" and it contains everything you could even dream about ;-)

Comment: Hi @zerkms, I'm not familiar with this, is there a way to update the dead ?link

Comment: @bummi could you please read the whole answer once again? I even provided a google request example that *still works* and returns tons of relevant results. I know googling is boring but please don't be that lazy. Thank you.